# MaxWidth and MaxHeight is not working in ImageView

Tags: android

I am using an `ImageView` in Android where I initially set the `layout_height` and `layout_width` to `wrap_content` as well as set the `maxHeight` and `maxWidth` attributes.

This is how it looks like in my layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profileImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxWidth="226dp"
    android:maxHeight="174dp"
    android:background="@drawable/photo" />
```

But when I pick a picture from the gallery then it covers my entire screen, ignoring the `maxWidth` and `maxHeight`. How can I  resolve this issue ?

Comment: You mean you're sending the image to another activity to display on click?

Comment: I am picking image from gallery and showing in this `imageview` and when I pick any big size image then it covers almost entire screen. It ignores the maxWidth and maxHeight

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Comment: why? any comment if you don't mind

Comment: it very bad solution if you have a lot of images and they change dynamically